# Synonym for Medium

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a synonym for the word "medium".
More precisely: The word will be used within the realm of mathematical modeling.

**My Question:**

Can I use the expressions "a porous medium" and "a porous milieu" synonymously?
This question refers to language-related aspects only. Whether this term is used in the scientific community is another question.

Comment: I don't see how you can detach this from the scientific community. You need to use the correct scientific term. "Medium" has specific meanings in different sciences which "milieu" does not. But you are required to do basic research so you should explain what you understand the meanings of "medium" and "milieu" to be, based on consulting a dictionary.

Comment: @StuartF, thanks a lot.

Comment: Also, it would be good to provide more information on context. Mathematical modelling can apply to almost anything. Are you modelling the behaviour of a specific medium?

Comment: @StuartF, the medium could be described as f.e. porous. Would I need to cite right now?

Answer (score 0):

Synonyms for "medium" in the context of modelling are for example, "substance", "field" and "material". You can also use the specific medium in question such as "gas", "vacuum", etc.